# Tensorflow dynamic RNN (LSTM): how to format input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tflearn

I have been given some data of this format and the following details:

```
person1, day1, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
person1, day2, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
...
person1, dayN, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
person2, day1, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
person2, day2, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
...
person2, dayN, feature1, feature2, ..., featureN, label
...
```

- there is always the same number of features but each feature might be a 0 representing nothing
- there is a varying amount of days available for each person, e.g. person1 has 20 days of data, person2 has 50

**The goal** is to predict the label of the person the following day, so the label for dayN+1, either on a per-person basis, or overall (per-person makes more sense to me). I can freely reformat the data (it is not large). Based on the above after some reading I thought a dynamic RNN (LSTM) could work best:

- recurrent neural network: because the next day relies on the previous day
- lstm: because the model builds up with each day
- dynamic: because not all features are present each day

If it does not make sense for the data I have, please stop me here.
The question is then:

**How to give/format this data for tensorflow/tflearn?**

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/nlp/dynamic_lstm.py) example using tflearn but I do not understand its input format so that I can 'mirror' it to mine. Similarly, have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324520/understanding-tensorflow-lstm-input-shape) post on a very similar question yet it seems like the samples the poster has are not related between each-other as they are in mine. My experience with tensorflow is limited to its [get started](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> dynamic: because not all features are present each day

You've got the wrong concept of dynamic here. Dynamic RNN in Tensorflow
means the graph is dynamically created during execution, but the inputs are always the same size (0 as the lack of a feature should work ok).

Anyways, what you've got here are sequences of varying length (day1 ... day?) of feature vectors (feature1 ... featureN). First, you need a [LSTM cell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell)

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMcell(size)
```

so you can then create a dynamically unrolled rnn graph using [tf.nn.dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn). From the docs:

> inputs: The RNN inputs.
>
> If time_major == False (default), this must be a Tensor of shape: [batch_size, max_time, ...], or a nested tuple of such elements.

where max_time refers to the input sequence length. Because we're using dynamic_rnn, the sequence length doesn't need to be defined during compile time, so your input placeholder could be:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, None, N))
```

Which is then fed into the rnn like

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x)
```

Meaning your input data should have the shape `(batch_size, seq_length, N)`. If examples in one batch have varying length, you should pad them with 0-vectors to the max length and pass the appropriate `sequence_length` parameter to `dynamic_rnn`

Obviously I've skipped a lot of details, so to fully understand RNNs you should probably read one of the many excellent RNN tutorials, like [this one](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-i.html) for example.

Comment: How to build up a RNN when the length of input data is arbitrary?

Comment: If by 'length of input data' you mean batch size, then you can declare x as having `shape=(None, None, N)` to be able to pass batches of arbitrary length. If you mean sequence length, then it's covered in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't think I can pad input data with 0-vectors to the max length in my application. Since in every time step, there are different input data with different length. In my view, if padding with 0-vectors, the network may get low performance because 0 has its own meaning for example position or label(one-hot encoding).

Comment: If you pass the `sequence_length` parameter to `dynamic_rnn` then it doesn't matter what you pad with, since tensorflow knows it's only for padding (so it won't affect the outcome). Padding with 0-vectors should be fine. See [here](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you, here is the details of my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897258/how-can-process-arbitrary-length-input-with-rnn-in-tensorflow